# How i can get the Principle ID of an Office 365 security group

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, user-information-list

I have an Office 365 security group (without email), and i want to add it to an Item permission, where the built-in action "Grant access to item or folder" will not work, as it only accept email addresses inside the Recipients list.

so i need to send an http request to SharePoint, as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1698921354933.png]

but for that i will need to know the PrincipleID of the group, the PrincipleId is the group id inside SharePoint site and not the group id inside office 365 ,, is there  way to get this Principle id? i can get it from the UI, as follow (which is 14):-

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can check in the Azure active directory in Azure portal to get the id. Do you want it in a dynamic nature within the flow? If yes, then you can use graph API: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Test')

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982512/how-to-search-the-group-by-the-displayname-using-microsoft-graph

Comment: @DikeshGandhi this will give me the group unique id, i need the principle id of the group within the SP site

Comment: @microsoftdeveloperdesigner, try step by step solution given here: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/11/05/sharepoint-online-grant-permissions-to-azure-ad-security-group-using-power-automate-and-rest-api/. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharePoint REST API with an OData filter to get the SharePoint ID.

For example, you can filter the `Title` with `eq` operator: `Title eq 'PMP-Admin'`

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/SiteUsers?$filter=Title%20eq%20%27PPM-Admin%27
```

The answer will be a JSON like that:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/Web/GetUserById(42)",
                    "uri": "https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/Web/GetUserById(42)",
                    "type": "SP.User"
                },
                "Id": 42,
                "IsHiddenInUI": false,
                "LoginName": "c:0t.c|tenant|some-guid|user",
                "Title": "PMP-Admin",
                "PrincipalType": 1,
                "Email": "",
                "Expiration": "",
                "IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser": false,
                "IsShareByEmailGuestUser": false,
                "IsSiteAdmin": false,
                "UserPrincipalName": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The SharePoint ID will be in the `Id` property.